# Can INDEX function in Excel return an Array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Referring to the below screenshot, I have a question about Index Function in MS Excel.
Can INDEX actually return an Array?
e.g. I have numbers in cells A1:A5 as seen in the screenshot. In Cells C1:C5 I put an Array Formula

```
{=INDEX(A1:A5,ROW(A1:A5))}
```

and it successfully returns numbers from A1:A5, indicating that INDEX can return an array in a set of cells.

However when I use a formula like this one

```
{=SUM(INDEX(A1:A5,ROW(A1:A5)))}
```

I was expecting return value of 15 but I get only the first element of the array i.e. 1.

Is this how it is? Can INDEX return an Array that can be used in other Array based formulas?

[image]

Comment: You can force INDEX to return an array by using a combination of N and IF functions like this: `=SUM(INDEX(A1:A5,N(IF(1,ROW(A1:A5)))))` - see this question for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187863/can-excels-index-function-return-array

Comment: you can use offset and match to return an array, i find it much easier than actually going to the trouble of making an array out of index etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:A5,0,1))
```

With `0` as the row argument, `INDEX` will return the entire column

Since you have only a single column, you can also use:

```
=SUM(INDEX(A1:A5,0))
```

which, of course, would be equivalent to

```
=SUM(A1:A5)
```

To expand on @BarryHoudini 's comment, for a non-contiguous array of returns from `INDEX`, you can use something like:

```
=SUM(INDEX(myRange,N(IF(1,{1,3,5}))))
```

which, in your example array, would return `9`

Comment: also +1 to @barry houdini's comment

Answer (score 0):

It was a way to "look left" in a lookup. So that's another way it can feed another function.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,INDEX(A1:B5,SEQUENCE(5),{2,1}),2,FALSE)
```

(Using `SEQUENCE()` 'cause this is for future interest by folks, but the couple different `ROW()` approaches work just fine.)

The key is that matrix constant at the end of the`INDEX()` function. One can reorganize the order of the columns in one's table as well as drop columns. So the table becomes column B, then column A so `VLOOKUP()` is satisfied because to it, it is "looking right" so everyone's happy.

I wager it can be used in a string setting in pick-apart formulas as well, but don't recall needing to bother. Though something might be appealing now that `SEEQUENCE()` lets one work with series constants in a much more straightforward manner. Hmmm...

So defintely not just collection functions like the SUM's and COUNT's of the Excel world.